FluentValidation TestHelper: Handling OverridePropertyName in Unit Tests
Question:
I'm using FluentValidation in my .NET application and have a custom validation method for phone numbers that uses .OverridePropertyName("phone_number"). The validation method works fine, but I'm encountering issues when writing unit tests using FluentValidation's TestHelper.
Here is the validation method:
public static IRuleBuilder<T, string> PhoneNumber<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
{
    var options = ruleBuilder.NotNull().WithMessage("Phone number is required")
        .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Phone number is required")
        .Matches(@"^[0-9]+$").WithMessage("Invalid Phone number")
        .OverridePropertyName("phone_number");

    return options;
}


And here are my unit tests:
[Theory]
[InlineData(null, true, "Phone number is required")]
[InlineData("", true, "Phone number is required")]
[InlineData("12345abc", true, "Invalid Phone number")]
[InlineData("1234567890", false)]
public void PhoneNumberValidationTests(string phoneNumber, bool shouldHaveError, string expectedErrorMessage = null)
{
    ValidateTest(rule => rule.PhoneNumber(), phoneNumber, shouldHaveError, expectedErrorMessage);
}

private void ValidateTest(System.Action<IRuleBuilderInitial<TestModel, string>> rule, string value, bool shouldHaveError, string expectedErrorMessage = null)
{
    var validator = new TestValidator(rule);
    var model = new TestModel { Property = value };
    var result = validator.TestValidate(model);

    if (shouldHaveError)
    {
        var errors = result.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.Property);
        if (expectedErrorMessage != null)
        {
            errors.WithErrorMessage(expectedErrorMessage);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result.ShouldNotHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.Property);
    }
}

private class TestModel
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}

private class TestValidator : AbstractValidator<TestModel>
{
    public TestValidator(System.Action<IRuleBuilderInitial<TestModel, string>> rule)
    {
        rule(RuleFor(x => x.Property));
    }
}


The tests fail when .OverridePropertyName("phone_number") is used. The error message indicates that it expected a validation error for property Property, but the validation errors are actually reported under phone_number.
Error Message:
FluentValidation.TestHelper.ValidationTestException : Expected a validation error for property Property
----
Properties with Validation Errors:
[0]: phone_number

How can I modify my tests to handle the OverridePropertyName properly and check for validation errors on the overridden property name?

You can achieve this using the another overload of the method ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor by specifying the property name.
Like this:
var errors = result.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor("phone_number");

